# Storybook with redux component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, storybook

I have a MERN stack with redux. I'm trying to build my UI components and I want to use storybook for easier workflow.

Thing is that I simply can't get it to work.

This is my component: `Navbar.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    return (
      <div className="navbar-fixed">
        <nav className="z-depth-0">
          <div className="nav-wrapper white">
            <Link
              to="/"
              style={{
                fontFamily: "monospace"
              }}
              className="col s5 brand-logo center black-text"
            >
              <i className="material-icons">code</i>
              {user.name}
            </Link>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(Navbar);
```

And this is my Story `Navbar.stories.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from '../components/layout/Navbar';

export default {
  title: 'Navbar',
  component: Navbar
};

export const SimpleStory = () => <Navbar/>;
```

this is the error that I'm getting:

```
Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Navbar)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Navbar)".
```

How can I make my Navbar component isolated from redux?

Comment: there's not a single comment. And I can't find much about it elsewhere. I must be doing something wrong, I just can't tell what.

Comment: Please show your App.js / Root Component

Comment: Duplicate question. Please follow this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58627894/5456476

Answer (score 3):

Your component seems to use react-redux, and it has no Redux store to connect to in story, so wrap story with provider can deal with that issue.
https://www.learnstorybook.com/intro-to-storybook/react/en/screen/

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from '../components/layout/Navbar';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store } from "../../src/index";

export default {
  title: 'Navbar',
  component: Navbar,
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Story />
      </Provider>
    ),
  ],
};

export const SimpleStory = () => <Navbar/>;
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer and add an explanation as to why you think this solution will work?